# How to display the playlist from google music player in my list view using android

Tags: android, media-player

Now I am working in an music player app, I have a tab for playlist in my app, I need to display the playlist names which is created in default music player, 
I have tried using external_content_uri, but nothing helps.

Please share your comments, it will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague so it is hard to gauge an appropriate answer.

But nonetheless are you populating playlists through a list or recyclerview? If the user clicks one of hte items, I'm assuming you want it to direct to another listview?

I'm going to assume that you want three listviews, and you're working with an API here:

1. Playlists
2. Playlist(from playlists)
3. Songs(from playlist)

What you can do is set a listener on each individual item for the listview to have it send information to the other listview activities. This way, you won't be populating listviews inside of listviews(this is terrible practice) and the user will be able to backtrack on each of them. You will probably send data throguh intents and have to use a serializable wrapper on each item, and have respective listviews receive the intents and populate the data using such. If you're working with an API here, make sure you make the proper object models to coordinate.

Again, your question is rather vague so I'm going off on alot of assumptions here.

Comment: Please find below for my source code, which i have tried, but I didn't get any playlist names in listview, 

`String filterQuery = arg1!=null?arg1.getString(FILTER_EXTRA):null;
String selection = null;
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filterQuery))
{
    selection=MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME+" LIKE '%"+filterQuery+"%'";
}
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, selection, null, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME+" COLLATE NOCASE ASC");`